# How to maintain Session Timeout handling in Android Application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

[image]I am new to Android App development.I have a small issue.Working on my Android Application suddenly hit "Home" Button so it goes to background after some time again go to "Home" and click my app icon it again getting started from my first screen instead of this i have keep the last viewed Activity and should show message like "Your Session timed out So Please Loging again the box with two EditText boxes" Then check the credentials and Allow the user to continue or redirect to Login Screen.How to achieve this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using Server Client architecture?

Comment: No i just want keep the login secure thats all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple in Android. you need to maintain `SharedPreferences`.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for better understanding of the concept.

This will work as

```
 ==> when ever you are trying to maintain login concept save user name in the sharedpreference.
 ==> once data is edited in prefernces.xml , the data in it can be check in any Activity.
```

For example, to save username, password and session ID, you can:

```
 SharedPreferences pref = myContexy.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
 edit.putString("User Name", username);
 edit.putString("Password", password);
 edit.putInt("Session ID", session_id);
 edit.commit();
```

and get them

```
 SharedPreferences pref = myContexy.getSharedPreferences("Session Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
 username = pref.getString("User Name", "");
 password = pref.getString("Password", "");
 session_id = pref.getInt("Session ID", 0);
```

Comment: I dont think it is safe to store user's password. It does not seem legal or good practice.

Comment: I totally agree. It's not safe.

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences` is definately the way to go, but to go into more detail for the timeout:

- Save the current timestamp in `onPause()` (-> `SharedPreferences`)
- Then in `onResume()` compare it, to check for a timeout

If you did not time-out just continue, otherwise show that nice screen, simply logout, self-destruct the device, or whatever you would like to do in that case :-)

Also you might consider implementing some kind of session manager class, to handle it on a higher level:
[Nice example/tutorial from android hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

Comment: Very clear explanation, +100 for self-destruct / Mission Impossible reference

Answer (score 1):

See this diagram for an explanation of the Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Override the appropriate methods in your activity to keep track of when it loses/regains focus.

Comment: According to your answer, the application will only get visible or invisible based on its activity life cycle. But the question is about how to maintain session time out, i.e. if session times out, all the activities from stack will be cleared and user will be navigated to log in screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the user login session then instead of having the preference in all the activities we can have handler inplace to do this.

1. Create Handler after the user logsin
2. Set sendMessageAtTime(Message, long), long is millisecond value. This will call the logout function that defined.